# JavaFX concurrency freezing ui

Tags: java, concurrency

i am looking into JavaFX now, specifically into concurrency. As my homework i decided to do an app, of which one of the functions is to read text file. For reference i used core java bonus chapter which is not in the book but available on website of horstmann (v1ch13fx.uitask.TaskDemo) and after finishing i tried it out and encountered an issue - the whole UI freezes together with reading the file, can be between few seconds and few minutes. Unless what i learned was not correct and just nonsense, shouldn't doing the reading on separate thread from UI prevent this from happening?

Can anyone who unedrstands this better have a look and tell me whether there is some problem with the code itself (tried same task with the app written by horstmann and same issue appears though) and advise me of any ways i could deal with this issue?

No matter what i do issue is the same, second day im at it now looking for sources online. Is it an issue with the code itself, or the concept of the task? And in the end this runs on damn powerful machine, which makes the headache even bigger.

```
public static void read(Stage stage, TextArea textArea, Label status, MenuItem open, MenuItem clear) {
    if(task != null) return;
    FileChooser chooser = new FileChooser();
    chooser.setInitialDirectory(new File(".."));
    chooser.getExtensionFilters().addAll(new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("Text files", "*.txt"));
    File file = chooser.showOpenDialog(stage);
    if(file == null) return;
    textArea.clear();
    task = new Task<>() {
        public Integer call() {
            int lines = 0;
            try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
                while(br.readLine() != null) {
                    String line = br.readLine();
                    Platform.runLater(() -> textArea.appendText(line + " \n"));
                    lines++;
                    updateMessage(lines + " lines read.");
                }
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return lines;
        }
    };
    execute.execute(task);`enter code here`
```

Comment: A runLater for every line is the culprit. And updateMessage will also slow things down.

Comment: I will be more thoughtful on this topic in the future. Basically the issue still appeared due to passing a significant amount of work to UI thread as i understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Joop Eggen is correct.  Your `runLater` calls are happening so fast, they are clogging up the JavaFX event queue, so JavaFX has no chance to do its normal painting and input handling.

A simple workaround is putting `Thread.sleep(20);` in your loop.

A better workaround, which won’t slow down your reading of the file, is to make your own buffer, and limit how often you update the TextArea:

```
task = new Task<>() {
    public Integer call() {
        int lines = 0;

        Collection<String> linesBuffer = new ArrayList<>(100_000);
        long timeOfLastAppend = System.nanoTime();

        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                linesBuffer.add(line);

                // Do not update the TextArea more than 10 times per second
                // (that is, every 100 million nanoseconds).
                long time = System.nanoTime();
                if (time - timeOfLastAppend >= 100_000_000L) {
                    timeOfLastAppend = time;

                    String text = String.join(" \n", linesBuffer) + " \n";
                    Platform.runLater(() -> textArea.appendText(text));

                    linesBuffer.clear();
                }

                lines++;
                updateMessage(lines + " lines read.");
            }

            if (!linesBuffer.isEmpty()) {
                String text = String.join(" \n", linesBuffer) + " \n";
                Platform.runLater(() -> textArea.appendText(text));
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return lines;
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, i will test this out when im back at the task. I was thinking to try something along the lines of array list, but your full solution is even better. Learned something new today, a good day.